# finding constants on the right side of a linear system

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to find all values of a, b, and c so that this:

$$\begin{cases}
&x  &- &3y &= a \\
&2y &- &z &= b \\
&x &- &5y &+ &z &= c
\end{cases}
$$

linear system has solutions. But I am finding that I end up with no solutions when following elimination, basing off of coefficient vs augmented matrix rank.

Based off of how the question was worded, I feel that I am expected to find solutions. Am I missing something here?

my elimination looks like:

$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & -3 & 0 &| &a \\
        0 & 2 & -1 &| &b \\
        1 & -5 & 1 &| &c \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$
-R1 + R3 --> R3
$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & -3 & 0 &| &a \\
        0 & 2 & -1 &| &b \\
        0 & -2 & 1 &| &c-a \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$
R2 + R3 --> R3
$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & -3 & 0 &| &a \\
        0 & 2 & -1 &| &b \\
        0 & 0 & 0 &| &-a+b+c \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

Coefficient matrix rank: 2 Augmented matrix rank: 3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT**

It is a correct way to solve.

Now observe that the system has solution if and only if $$-a+b+c=0\implies c=a-b$$

With this condition the system becomes

\begin{bmatrix}
        1 & -3 & 0 &| &a \\
        0 & 2 & -1 &| &b \\
               \end{bmatrix}

which has (infinite) solutions for every $a,b$ (can you see why?).

Comment: Thank you!! and would that be because we cannot find a value for x, y, or z without using a free variable?

Comment: @cbm If $c\neq a-b$ the last equation in the RREF becomes impossible since you should have$ 0=-a+b+c \neq 0$. For $c= a-b$ the third equation is satisfied since it becomes $0=0$. The remaining two equations have infitely many solutions since rank is 2 and the null space has dim=1 or, in other words, you have 2 independent equations with 3 uknowns, thus with a free variable.

Answer (score 0):

The vector equation $A\mathbf x=\mathbf b$ has a solution iff $\mathbf b$ lies in the column space of the matrix $A$. If you compute that column space for your system of linear equations, you will end up with constraints on the constants $a$, $b$ and $c$.